# Changing default container factory bean from kafkaListenerContainerFactory to my custom container factory

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka

In spring-kafka docs we can read that default container factory is assumed to be available with a bean name of `kafkaListenerContainerFactory` unless an explicit default has been provided through configuration.

I would like to ask if it is possible to change configuration to use my custom container factory bean (for example. `customKafkaListenerContainerFactory`) not `kafkaListenerContainerFactory`?

Code example -> if we type

```
@KafkaListener(id = "cat", topics = "myTopic")
public void listen(String data, Acknowledgment ack) {
    ...
    ack.acknowledge();
}
```

then default containerFactory bean is `customKafkaListenerContainerFactory` not `kafkaListenerContainerFactory`

**To be more precisely** -> if I don't provide any containerFactory attribute then `customKafkaListenerContainerFactory` is used NOT `kafkaListenerContainerFactory`

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can by using [containerFactory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/annotation/KafkaListener.html#containerFactory--) attribute in `@KafkaListener` annotation, you can set the custom kafka container factory bean

> The bean name of the KafkaListenerContainerFactory to use to create the message listener container responsible to serve this endpoint.

```
@KafkaListener(id = "cat", topics = "myTopic", containerFactory="customKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
public void listen(String data, Acknowledgment ack) {
   ...
  ack.acknowledge();
}
```

Or you can override the default [kafkaListenerContainerFactory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#with-java-configuration) in Config class. And as said by @Gary Russell just use the same bean name, it will replace Boot's which is conditional on the presence of a bean with that name

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class Config {

   @Bean
   @ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
   ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Integer, String>
                    kafkaListenerContainerFactory(ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Integer, String> factory =
                            new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    configurer.configure(factory,consumerFactory());
    // set custom properties
    return factory;
   }

   @Bean
   public ConsumerFactory<Integer, String> consumerFactory() {
      return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
   }

   @Bean
   public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, embeddedKafka.getBrokersAsString());
    ...
    return props;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use `containerFactory` attribute. I just want to change default kafkaListenerContainerFactory to `customKafkaListenerContainerFactory`.

To be more precisely -> if I don't provide any containerFactory attribute then `customKafkaListenerContainerFactory` is used NOT `kafkaListenerContainerFactory`

Comment: You can override in the config class @Syma

Comment: Just use the same bean name; it will replace Boot's which is conditional on the presence of a bean with that name `@ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory") ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(...)`. The annotation always looks for `kafkaListenerContainerFactory` unless specifically set.

Comment: @Deadpool - it's best to use `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer` in a custom bean definition so you can apply the Boot config properties and then set others.

Comment: Thank you @GaryRussell pointing me right direction, let me update the answer

Comment: Ok but what about situation when i declared bean kafkaListenerContainerFactory (it's declared in spring context) but anyway i want to redirect all default containerFactory to `customKafkaListenerContainerFactory`. I cannot use `@ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")` because bean is declared. This annotations is used to load a bean only if a given bean is missing

Comment: I just want to have two preconfigured container factories (`kafkaListenerContainerFactory` and `customKafkaListenerContainerFactory`) but when containerFactory attribute is not set then `@KafkaListener` will be looking for `customKafkaListenerContainerFactory` not for `kafkaListenerContainerFactory` as it's default.